# define an ENV in Dockerfile not working

Tags: docker, linux, npm

I wrote a Docker file as below. However I define a system variable (which is necessary for NPM build) in many formats and multi where in that file, after creating image and running container I need to enter in to the container OS and manually export the variable and run build for my project.

```
FROM node:18.16.1-bullseye
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies in the container
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

# Copy the rest of the application to the container
COPY . .

ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
RUN export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"

RUN npm run build

# Specify the command to run when the container starts
CMD ["npm", "run", "preview"]
```

Comment: could you please show us your **doker run** command?

Comment: i think you need pass your NODE_OPTIONS on your *docker run* command

Comment: I use dicker-compose run command: docker-compose up -d --build
@MDNasirulIslam